Iterate over groups of PyArrow table
In pandas I can iterate over groups in groupby:
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: data = {'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [2, 4, 3, 5, 6]}

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [6]: for _, sub_df in df.groupby('a'):
   ...:     print(sub_df)
   ...:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  1  3
   a  b
3  2  5
4  2  6

Is there an efficient way to do that in PyArrow? Say I start with
tbl = pa.table(data)

All I could come with is:
In [16]: for x in pc.unique(tbl['a']):
    ...:     print(tbl.filter(pc.equal(tbl['a'], x)))
    ...:
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
b: int64
----
a: [[1,1,1]]
b: [[2,4,3]]
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
b: int64
----
a: [[2,2]]
b: [[5,6]]

but this involves scanning the whole 'a' column multiple times...is there a more performant way?

there isn't much you can do after a group by beside aggregating in pyarrow https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.TableGroupBy.html

Table.group_by can aggregate into list arrays.
>>> data = {'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [2, 4, 3, 5, 6]}
>>> groups = pa.table(data).group_by(['a']).aggregate([('b', 'list')])
>>> groups
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
b_list: list<item: int64>
  child 0, item: int64
----
a: [[1,2]]
b_list: [[[2,4,3],[5,6]]]

The groups are in a single table, but the rows can be iterated.
>>> for row in groups.to_struct_array():
...     print(row['a'], row['b_list'])
...     
1 [2, 4, 3]
2 [5, 6]

>>> for row in groups.to_struct_array():
...     table = pa.table({'b': row['b_list'].values})
...     table = table.append_column('a', pa.repeat(row['a'], len(table)))


Thanks @a-coady - how would you then subgroups as PyArrow tables, as in the original example?
